# Handlebars - How to get another collection {{#each something1}} while rendering another by {{#each something2}}

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I'm currently using Handlebars as my view engine. I have two collections: `comments` and `countries`. Here is my code:

```
{{#each comments}}
    //somecode
    {{#each countries}}
    {{/each}}
    //somecode
{{/each}}
```

The problem is that Handlebars automatically finds the field name `countries` inside `comments` the collection, while they are isolated. How can I prevent it? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You would need to "step-up" a context level, as in `{{#each ../countries}}`. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context